# Upgrading Apache messes up html/php code

Tags: php, html, apache, wamp

I'm trying to figure out this php/html code right now which is hosted on Apache 2.2.x (ancient I know).

This code:

```
<img src="{self tempdir}images/banner.jpg" width="1060px" height="410px" />
```

On Apache 2.2.21:
looks like this in browser->view source:

```
<img src="/template/default/index/images/banner.jpg" width="1060px" height="410px" />
```

When I upgrade to Apache 2.2.23, it breaks:
The same code looks like this in browser->view source:

```
<img src="<?=$this->tempdir?>images/banner.jpg" width="1060px" height="410px" />
```

So it looks like the php code isn't rendering if it begins with

```
"<?"
```

I can't seem to find a solution to this. Anyone know where to look in apache configs to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried changing it to “<?php” instead? I had a problem with that when I upgraded to php7 which has the short tags disabled by default

Comment: So I didn't know that it was called short tag. I was able to google how to turn on short tag parsing and found that it can be turned on in apache's bin/php.ini via short_open_tag and asp_tag. Thanks for your help.